# Parsing Javascript values to Django views

Tags: javascript, python, django, google-maps

I am new to Django and I am just trying to figure it out and I did posted it in official Django google group but no answer. I am working with Google Map API in my Django template for GeoLocation and I intend to populate DB table dynamically after extracting information from JavaScript in my Django template. Following is the code:

```
var map, infoWindow;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 6
    });
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
        map.setCenter(pos);
      }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
  }

  function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                          'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                          'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
    infoWindow.open(map);
  }
```

I need to save longitude and latitude with GeoLocation Info about the location in human readable format in my model. My Model is

```
class Address(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, models.CASCADE)
   latitude = models.CharField(max_length=10)
   longitude = models.CharField(max_length=10)
   address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   .....
```

My form is:

```
class UserAddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
            model = Address
            fields = ['latitude', 'longitude', 'address'}
```

I need to figure it out in my view how to do it.
It will be great if someone can refer me to right direction because I am really having hard time to figure it out as newbie.

Answer (score 1):

**i don't have enough reputation to comment that why i'm trying to answer what i understood from this, please don't mind**

I faced the same issue when i was doing live Forex data streaming display. You can do one thing. What i did is reverse approach(i don't know exactly  how to do this).

1. Write a python script using Google api to access to those details
   and collect it.
2. Store it in DB. then pass this data to template over **Django-restframework**
3. you will be able at access those data in js now.
4. You can make ajax call using **set-interval** function to make it
       refresh every interval.
   if you do this it will invoke your view function that every particular interval so it will be saved in db over model as well as displaying in template.

i hope it helps.

Comment: i did not find any example, i tried my own and it worked.  My goal was to scrape a data from truefx and dumb in db then displaying as table in template.

Answer (score 1):

```
def fx(request):
#template = loader.get_template('fx.html')
template = loader.get_template('fx.html')
fj = fxdata()
r0 = fj[0]
r1 = fj[1]
r2 = fj[2]
r3 = fj[3]
r4 = fj[4]
r5 = fj[5]
r6 = fj[6]


# context = {"Symbol": sym, "Time":time, "Ask":ask, "Bid":bid,"High":high,"low":low,"Close":close}
context = {"R0":r0, "R1":r1, "R2":r2, "R3":r3, "R4":r4, "R5":r5, "R6":r6}

for key, index in context.items():
    a=context[key]
    forex_instance = forex.objects.create(symbol=str(a[0]),datetime = str(a[1]), ask = float(a[2]), bid = float(a[3]), high = float(a[4]),low = float(a[5]), close=float(a[6]) )



html = template.render(context)
return HttpResponse(html)
```

In this view function `fj = fxdata()` return a scrape data  and stored in db
meanwhile i'm trying to display this data in my template so i used `html = template.render(context)` the context dictionary i passed to template over **HttpResponse**

Then I made a **Ajax Call** on the same template with **setInterval** using div id.

SO its started refreshing the templates. It call view function every time it refreshes. The data also keep storing in DB.

Then I used **Django rest-framework** to export this data into **JS**